# Ionic Android Build - com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base Error

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, android-build

My error:

> :app:preReleaseBuild FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being
requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0], [16.4.0,16.4.0]], 
but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree
using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I reinstalled the npm and cordova plugins for Firebase, I deleted the node-modules, the plugins and everything but the issue is still there and can't build the project.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This resolved my problem:

1. In your project folder execute **cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue**
2. ionic cordova platform rm android
3. ionic cordova platform add android.

You can find the solution here: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/pull/1058

Comment: Thank you so much! I struggled all day long with no success, but your solving steps worked in my case. Thanks again!

Comment: sir i have tried but i got :                                                                                                Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

for ionic , go to projects.gardle and
change `cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.+  to (17.5.0)`